# How can I take multiple combinations of the different lengths from the same list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools

Suppose I have the tuple (3, 2, 1, 4). I would like to find every possible combination that involves taking 3 elements from range(5), 2 elements from range(5), 1 elements from range(5), and then 4 elements from range(5). The order between each individual combination matters, so I cannot just take combinations of length 9 from range(5) or something like that.

In case what I wrote above wasn't clear, a sample combination might be

```
[0, 1, 4,   2, 3,   2,   0, 1, 2, 3].
```

I introduced the spacing in the list above just to make it clear that the ordering between them matters.

I imagine that this should be simple to implement with itertools, but I just don't know how.

Comment: Do the subselections need to be ordered (so that a sample could start `[0, 1, 4]` but not `[0, 4, 1]`)?

Comment: @DSM No, the ordering in the subselections does not matter.

Comment: I may not have asked that well.  Do you need the variants of your example starting `[0,4,1]` to show up in the output or not?

Comment: I don't need those variants to show up in the output, in fact I need them to _not_ show up. (I hope I'm interpreting your question accurately.)

Comment: Yep, that was it. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for [combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) rather than [permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), the following should do what you want.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations, product

lengths = (3, 2, 1, 4)
for L in product(*(combinations(range(5), length) for length in lengths)):
    print(list(chain.from_iterable(L)))
```

Comment: Quite elegant. Way to go.

Comment: Unfortunately I received an error message when I tried your code. There was a syntax error on the last line with "list". Also, what does the star in product do? Edit: it's because I'm using Python 3 that I got an error message on the last line. I'll try again.

Comment: Apologies I was using Python 2 which doesn't require parentheses with `print`. Now fixed. Star in product tells it to unpack the different combinations as arguments https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists